# GitHub link on careers.stackoverflow.com is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, github

On http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit/49504

- I click 'My profile', and then 'add github'
- The link points to http://careers.stackoverflow.com/import/githubauth/writing/49504, but this quickly redirects to http://careers.stackoverflow.com/?code=de4cef6a4d230b1e5eaa (The Careers home page.)
- Repeat. The cycle never ends.

Something seems to be going wrong with your github auth callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, this should be resolved. Try it again?